# C++ Using std::transform on a vector of structures

Tags: c++, vector, struct, transform

I have a `C++` application with a `struct` which looks like:

```
struct test_struc {
    std::string name;
    int x;
    int y;
    std::vector<int> data;
};
```

And I would like to transform two `std::vector<test_struc>` using the lines according to their `data` element in the structure. So far, I have the code:

```
std::vector<test_struc> first = <from somewhere else>;
std::vector<test_struc> second = <from somewhere else>;

std::vector<int> result;
std::transform (second.begin(), second.end(), first.begin(), result.begin(), op_xor);
```

where `op_xor` is:

```
int op_xor (int &i,
            int &j) {
    return  i^j;
}
```

This works well if `first` and `second` are vectors of `int`, but since they are not, I don't know how to tell the code to use the `data` element of `test_struc` as arguments to `std::transform`.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? Or is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just so you know, there's already http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bit_xor. And IIRC, you're not allowed to modify things in a `transform` call, so taking by non-const reference is bad. If `test_struct` has a logical definition for bitwise XOR, overload the operator. If not, make your functor take those objects and operate on the appropriate members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binary functor must take two `test_struct`s:

```
int op_xor (const test_struct& i,
            const test_struct& j) 
{
    return  42; // replace wit your desired logic.
}
```

It isn't clear what exactly you want the functor to do, but it should operate on the `test_struct`s and return an int.

Comment: That was much simpler than I was trying to make it! Thanks! I'll accept as soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 4):

Note that at least with a modern compiler, you probably want to implement the operation as a lambda expression, so it would look something like:

```
std::transform(second.begin(), second.end(), 
               first.begin(),
               std::back_inserter(result),
               [](test_struct const &a, test_struct const &b) { 
                   return a.y ^ b.y; 
               });
```

Minor aside: as it was, you had UB, trying to write through `result.begin()` when the size of `result` was 0. You could either use `back_inserter` as above, or you could define `result` initializing its size to `second.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Or use lambdas.
And remember size of other vectors must be the same or more than "second"

```
  result.resize(second.size());
    std::transform(second.begin(), second.end(), first.begin(), result.begin(),
 [](test_struct & one, test_struct & two){ return one.x ^ two.x; });
```

But Jerry's example with back_inserter is better

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it using boost::transform and boost phoenix lambdas:

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;
using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg2;

boost::transform(second, first, std::back_inserter(result), (&arg1)->*&test_struc::x ^ (&arg2)->*&test_struc::x);
```

First and second arguments of `boost::transform` are ranges, so you do not have to write `second.begin(), second.end(), first.begin()` here.